# iPad/iTunes: In iTunes How do I drill down to in a folders list when transferring docs on my iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad

My Google-fu is failing me utterly.  I'll walk through an example of the problem with the app Office2 HD however I have the exact same issue with other apps too such as Goodreader.  I'm sure this is:

1) A user problem (hi!) or;
2) Itunes being a pain

I Have the app Office2 HD on my iPad.  I have created a folder tree on my IPad using Office2 HD.  I have multiple 'top level' folders with a variety of Office2 HD docs inside them.

When I have iTunes open and select my iPad device I can go to the app tab.  Towards the bottom of that screen is a 'File Sharing' option and it lists the apps that have files to share, including Office2 HD.  When I click that app a list of my folders appears to the right but I cannot drill down in them. What am I doing wrong?  I can rename the folder by single clicking their names but can't find a way to drill down into those folders within iTunes. Double clicking the name or icon for each folder doesn't do anything.

iPad is running 4.2.1, iTunes is version 10.1.0.56.

What am I missing, superuser? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can using iTunes. But you want to try it with third party app like this: http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/

But again, this is one of iOS devices limitations. Can you try deleting it from the app itself instead of from iTunes?

Comment: Thanks, I had a suspicion it s an iOS limitation.  The link was exactly what I needed, appreciated :)